# Python 3 Tkinker Text Box: "IndentationError: unexpected indent" Whenever I add new text to result text box

Tags: python, text, calculator, indentation

I'm trying to calculate the result of calculator inputs from the result text of my calculator window.  It starts with a "0" by default.

When, for example, I add 3:
"0 + 3"

However, when I add another action, like add 4, I get this:
"0 + 3

- 4"

For some reason, I keeping getting these indents when I try to add further calculator input.
When I attempt to calculate the result, I'm met with "IndentationError: unexpected indent."

Idk why tkinker or python is doing this.

calculator.py

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from classes_GUI import *


# Store input number
def storeInput(entry_text, result_text, action):
    numb = 0.0

    try:
        numb = float(entry_text.retrieveTextInput())
    except ValueError:
        print('Please enter a valid number')
        return

    num = entry_text.retrieveTextInput()

    input_texts = dict([
        (1, ' + ' + str(num)),
        (2, ' - ' + str(num)),
        (3, ' * ' + str(num)),
        (4, ' / ' + str(num)),
        (5, ' % ' + str(num)),
        (6, ' // ' + str(num)),
        (7, ' ** ' + str(num))
    ])

    result_text.changeText(input_texts[action])
    entry_text.clearText()


# Calculate result
def calcResult(entry_text, result_text):
    result = eval(result_text.retrieveTextInput())
    entry_text.clearText()
    result_text.changeText(str(result), True)
```

classes_GUI.py

```
# Create a data block for text
class TextBlock(tk.Text):
    def __init__(self, master, row, column, text='', **kwargs):
        tk.Text.__init__(self, master, **asdict(TextDc(**kwargs)))

        self.grid(row=row, column=column)
        self.insert('1.end', text)

    # Clear text
    def clearText(self):
        self.delete('1.0', 'end')

    # Change text
    def changeText(self, new_txt, clear=False):
        self.config(state='normal')
        if clear:
            self.clearText()
        self.insert('end', new_txt)
        self.config(state='disabled')

    # Retrieve input from text box
    def retrieveTextInput(self):
        return self.get('1.0', 'end')
```

Comment: It sounds like you are getting the indentation error at runtime during the `eval` operation. It would be worth clarifying that.

Comment: Would it be better to use a single line `tk.Entry` widget instead? You could take the resulting text and do `text.replace("\n", " ").strip()` to make it a single line python statement.

Comment: What do you mean use a single line tk.Entry widget instead.  Also, I tried using the suggestion for the resulting text, yet I get the same result.

Comment: Well, looks like I found the culprit.  The indent is resulting from when I get "num" in line 17 of calculator.py.  Now to figure out how to get rid of it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ok I found the solution to the problem:

```
# Store input number
def storeInput(entry_text, result_text, action):
    numb = 0.0

    try:
        numb = float(entry_text.retrieveTextInput())
        numb = str(numb)
    except ValueError:
        print('Please enter a valid number')
        return

    input_texts = dict([
        (1, ' + ' + numb),
        (2, ' - ' + numb),
        (3, ' * ' + numb),
        (4, ' / ' + numb),
        (5, ' % ' + numb),
        (6, ' // ' + numb),
        (7, ' ** ' + numb)
    ])

    result_text.changeText(input_texts[action])
    entry_text.clearText()
```

The problem was that I was reading the number input (in this case, the var numb) as a str rather than a float.  Reading the variable as a float, and then converting it to a str solved the issue.

Comment: No; the problem was that you had separate `num` and `numb` variables.

Comment: Looking at it more closely: the original approach made little sense, but it did check that the value was convertible to `float` and then re-get and use the value. In the new code, you convert to float and back again. The issue is that `float` **can accept a string with a trailing newline**; but the round-trip conversion removes that newline for you.